# Is there an idiom for something that doesn't seem to match or match?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom for something that doesn't seem to match or match? For example, let's say the last piece of the jigsaw puzzle doesn't match the rest of the puzzle for some reason even though you would expect it to match it? I am looking for an expression that closely match this meaning.

Comment: Yes - see [odd one out](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Odd+One+Out)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two that come close:

[Odd man out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/odd%20man%20out)

[Black sheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_sheep)